# How to get my auto complete to display after typing in a letter or word

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete

Right now all my words are displayed before you even start typing. I would like the words to display after you start typing. Im having a brain fart on how to make the words remain hidden until you start typing a letter and then it filters the results based on what you type.

[image]

```
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
    </script>

css

* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
```

background-color: #eee;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to hide from start, pure CSS

```
#myUL li {
  display: none
}
```

Then when typing with it never hides (if not having the CSS above) because you don't set anything in `display` when there is a match `li[i].style.display = ""`, change to `li[i].style.display = "block"` and test if `input.value` has some length like this:

```
li[i].style.display = input.value.length && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ? "block" : "none";
```

also you are checking for text inside `a`, no need for that, you can check for text in the `li`

```js
function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  const li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    const txtValue = li[i].textContent || li[i].innerText;
    li[i].style.display = input.value.length && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ? "block" : "none";
  }
}

myInput.addEventListener('keyup', myFunction)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li {
  display: none
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by initially hiding the list and checking the length of your input variable afterward. If the length is greater than zero, append a class `show`. Else, remove the class again. In Vanilla JS, you can do this by accessing the elements `classList`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");

  if (filter.length > 0) {
    ul.classList.add('show');
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  } else {
    ul.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
#myUL.show {
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee; 
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```